# How to copy different license files on respective boxes with ansible

Tags: ansible

I have two files :

1. `-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2943 Sep  9 09:17 artifactory_1.lic`
2. `-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   14 Sep 14 18:54 artifactory_2.lic`

I want them to copy on two different boxes:

- box-01.xyz.com and
- box-02.xyz.com

destination dir is same on both boxes:

```
/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory
```

Could anyone please let me know how to do that with anisble.

Comment: @larsks I have tried by doing to delegate_to option in separate ansible copy tasks. 

One more idea in my mind is to do it via passing the file against the hostnames in host file. Not sure how to pass the file.

Comment: Why not just use the `copy` module?  Can you update your question (i.e., do not add a comment) to show your attempt at writing a playbook?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and it worked for me:

in hosts file:

[jfrog]

192.168.56.102 node_lic=roles/jfrog-install/files/artifactory_1.lic

192.168.56.103 node_lic=roles/jfrog-install/files/artifactory_2.lic

in playbook:

name: updating licence for jfrog

copy:

```
src: "{{ node_lic }}"

dest: /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/artifactory.lic

owner: artifactory

group: artifactory

mode: 0644
```

Comment: you can use it in `host_vars` instead of using variable in inventory